# select statement with subqueries against two databases

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the below code to show what I am "trying" to accomplish in a stored procedure:

```
    select * from
    (   
    select to_char(sum(aa.amount)) 
    from additional_amount aa, status st
    where aa.int_tran_id = st.int_tran_id
    and st.stage in ('ACHPayment_Confirmed')
    and aa.entry_timestamp > ( 
                              select to_date(trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))+1), 'DD-MON-RR') AS "day 1" 
                              from dual
                              )

    )
     UNION ALL
  (
    select distinct it.debit_acct as "debit_accounts"
    from internal_transactions it
    where it.debit_acct IN ( select texe_cnasupro
                              from service.kndtexe, service.kndtctc
                              where texe_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
                              and tctc_cntipcli = 'C'
                            )
    )
      union all
    (select distinct it.credit_acct as "credit_account"
    from internal_transactions it
    where it.credit_acct IN (select texe_cnasupro
                              from service.kndtexe, service.kndtctc
                              where texe_cncclipu = tctc_cncclipu
                              and tctc_cntipcli = 'C'
                              )
    )
    ;
```

Output:

```
TO_CHAR(SUM(AA.AMOUNT))                
----------------------------------------
130250292.22                            
6710654504                               
0000050334                               
2535814905                               
0007049560                                          
5 rows selected
```

The top row of the output is what I need in the SP as output based on the below two queries which I am guessing needs to be sub-queried against the top select statement.

The top select is to select the sum of the amount a table with a join against another table for filtering (output:**130250292.22**).

The second and third selects is actually to check that the accounts in the internal_transactions table are signed up for the corresponding two tables in the service db which is a different db on the same server(owned by the same application).

The tables in the "service" db do not have the same common primary keys as in the first select which is against the same database.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: create db link on another db and give access on db link and table to 1st db schema.

Comment: i can access tables in the second db from the 1st db where the SP lies. I am accessing "service." in the code which is the second db.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, but I do know you can simplify this bit:

```
to_date(trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1))+1), 'DD-MON-RR') AS "day 1"
```

to this

```
trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
```

and you don't need a SELECT from DUAL to do that either.

```
and aa.entry_timestamp > trunc (sysdate, 'mm')
```